# Optimal image size for eshopo and resizing?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am currently developing a ecommerce site which ofcourse contains images for each product. The layout used requires 3 different image sizes;

Product overview size: W: 203, H: 186
Main image on product page: W: 471, H: 260
Thumbnails on product page: W: 90, H: 84
(all pixel sizes).

The goal is that one should only upload 1 image - and then my resize script should just be able to resize the image to the desired, and predefined, sizes. i have tried and tried to find the optimal size, but there is no size that will resize to all the sizes mentioned above - so perhaps i need to change some of the sizes above? And what would be the perfect staring point - ie. what size should be upload with the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is that you've got three completely different aspect ratios there.

You're better off maintaining the aspect ratio while resizing and then padding it out with blank space.